# Zend Framework in a subfolder

Tags: zend-framework, .htaccess

I have installed a Zend Framework application in a subfolder, something like this:

```
www.mydomain.com/temp/zend-application/
```

Now the problem is all stylesheets, javascript files and also all links use relative paths, such as:

```
/css/styles.css
/js/jquery.js
/controller/action
```

And these go to the main domain like this:

```
www.mydomain.com/css/styles.css
www.mydomain.com/js/jquery.js
www.mydomain.com/controller/action
```

So how to make it work in that subfolder?

My .htacces file looks like this now:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Exclude some directories from URI rewriting
#RewriteRule ^(dir1|dir2|dir3) - [L]

RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
```

EDIT: I have solved the problem by using setBaseUrl() method of front controller. Now the problem is how to edit my .htaccess file.

Comment: Were you able to get this working? What did you ultimately end up modifying in your .htaccess file?

Answer (score 2):

The best solution would be to [set a BaseUrl](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.request.html#zend.controller.request.http.baseurl) in your application. This should be detected automatically if you set a [RewriteBase](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) in your .htaccess. The router and other components have a knowledge of this setting and can generate appropriate links.

There's a [view helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.baseurl) which makes linking to assets easier.

Alternatively you can fix those links with a  tag in the document head.

```
<html>
<head>
<base href="http://www.mydomain.com/temp/zend-application/">
</head>
```

Further reading at http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_base.asp

Answer (score 0):

I would definetly use baseUrl() view helper preppended to the CSS's and JS's paths.