# Zend Framework: Page not found

Tags: zend-framework

I have developed a web application with Zend Framework which root is http://www.demo31.com/validacion/demo31/ but when I call that url I've got the next error:

```
Page not found

Request Parameters:

array (
  'controller' => 'validacion',
  'action' => 'demo31',
  'module' => 'default',
)
```

I want that the values of array would be next:

```
array (
  'controller' => 'index',
  'action' => 'index',
  'module' => 'default',
)
```

And my .htaccess is correct.

So, what do I have to do what I want?

Comment: How are your routes configured?

Answer (score 2):

Zend framework normally operates as per routes. If a particular URL is not reaching your code, then you have to configure routes to do that.

```
    $router = $front -> getRouter();
    $routePage = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/:controller/:action', array(
    /*                                             ^ Things to notice
                                                     Only two parameters are 
                                                     asked from the route */
        'controller' => 'default',
        'action'    => 'index',
        'module'    => 'default' //Predefine the module as `default
    ));
    $router -> addRoute('default', $routePage);
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, ZF assumes that the app is located in the root of the domain so that's why it treats validacion as a controller.

[Zend Framework in a subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550840/zend-framework-in-a-subfolder)